# Call method in parent class from child class

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, parent-child

This might seem like a stupid question, but is it possible for an object to call a method from the object which instantiated it?

Specifically if I have a class A which extends JFrame to provide a GUI and class B and C which are of the type JPanel with various components, which class A object changes between B and C to display different content to the user.
Is it possible for object of class B to call method of class A without creating another object of class A inside B but call the upper A object which has B inside it?

Comment: You can set A to B when instantiating it.

Comment: Is it like  1. A has an object of B... 2. A has a method `methodA` 3. You want to call `methodA` from B?

Comment: Yeah.. So for example A object which is overall empty JPanel container with menu, it in turn calls B object which is a JPanel with components and when a user interacts with a component eg button. That B button action event calls a method of A which changes the display depending on the button, if that makes sense..

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way I see is to pass A into both B and C, either via a parameter or an extension to B/C that holds an A instance and has a setter.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need something like this.

```
    class A {
        private B b;
        public void method() {
            b = new B(this);
        }
    }

    class B {
        private A a;
        public B(A a) {
            this.a = a;
        }
        void callAMethod() {
            a.method();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to place reference to your A object that created B or/and C objects inside of them for example by using setters or passing them as constructor parameter.

```
class A extends JFrame{
    void someMethod(){System.out.println("methods body");}
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        A a=new A();
        B b=new B();
        b.setCreator(a);
        b.test();
    }

}
class B extends JPanel{
    private A creator;
    public void setCreator(A creator) {
        this.creator = creator;
    }

    void test(){
        creator.someMethod();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guys, this has really given me something to work with. I'll give this a whirl and see how it goes. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Consider also that in the Swing framework exists diferent ways to get the hierarchy of components like  [getParent()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Component.html#getParent%28%29) or [getRoot()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/swing/SwingUtilities.html#getRoot%28java.awt.Component%29) .

Answer (score 0):

The best solution would be for the code doing the instantiation to pass a reference for itself to the object it is creating / has created.

It is theoretically possible for an object to find out which *class* created it (by creating an `Exception` and looking at its stacktrace) ... but there's no way within the executing application to find out the creating *instance*.